# Change relative font size for chart label in ggplot 2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the mtcars dataset, I wrote the following code which shows text labels in the chart with font sizes that depend on their counts of 'carb'. I would like to enlarge the relative font sizes of these labels because the smallest - count of 3 on the y-axis- is too small.  I've found similar post, but nothing directly addressing this issue.

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb)) +
   stat_count(aes(y = ..count..),  
      show.legend = F, geom = "text") +
      element_text(aes(size = ..count.., label = ..count..))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual size of the numbers that are printed is controlled by `scale_size_continuous`. The scale takes the argument `range`, which defines the sizes to be used for the smallest and largest object. By default, `range = c(1,6)`. You can play with the two numbers until you get the desired result.

Default values:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb)) +
  stat_count(aes(y = ..count..),  
             show.legend = F, geom = "text") +
  element_text(aes(size = ..count.., label = ..count..)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 6))
```

[image]

Enlarge small numbers, but keep maximum size the same:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb)) +
  stat_count(aes(y = ..count..),  
             show.legend = F, geom = "text") +
  element_text(aes(size = ..count.., label = ..count..)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 6))
```

[image]

Enlarge all numbers:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb)) +
  stat_count(aes(y = ..count..),  
             show.legend = F, geom = "text") +
  element_text(aes(size = ..count.., label = ..count..)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 12))
```

[image]